# How to diagnose a crash from system logs?

Tags: crash, logs, macos

I know you can get to the system logs from the Console and/or from the command line.

That said, I don't know how to read them very well. How can I tell which events are related to a crash and which ones are not?

Comment: There are different pieces of information inside crash logs. Some parts you won't understand without understanding assembly or general binary debugging and programming software, others are pretty simple to follow. Check this one to see a somewhat easier process I used to explain a possible source for a crash: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153235/sudden-unexpected-logouts/169323#169323

Answer (score 1):

Here's good Apple [site (Technical Note TN2123)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html) describing Crash Logs.