# More sudden, unexpected logouts

Tags: macos, crash, login-screen

I've just started seeing behavior similar to [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153235/sudden-unexpected-logouts) on 10.12.3 "Sierra".  Both times, I was using Chrome to look at web sites which showed moving images.  Suddenly I found myself looking at the login screen.

Here's as much of the crash log as will fit:

```
Process:               WindowServer [65813]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer
Identifier:            WindowServer
Version:               600.00 (13)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           WindowServer [65813]
User ID:               88

Date/Time:             2017-02-19 10:05:54.859 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.3 (16D32)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        2BE6EB64-8438-1423-8697-C7A9AEA45784

Sleep/Wake UUID:       578F1DF2-54A5-4E7D-98C8-B96F0F4F29B8

Time Awake Since Boot: 890000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       44000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000040
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x40:
-->
    __TEXT                 000000010ef96000-000000010ef97000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/WindowServer

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.IOAccelerator         0x00007fffd5d8509d IOAccelContextAddResource + 4
1   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver   0x000000011533feba Gen7Context::CheckOOM(USC::IM_Shader*, USC::IM_Shader*, USC::IM_Shader*, USC::IM_Shader*, USC::IM_Shader*, unsigned long long, bool&) + 2282
2   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver   0x000000011533f5c9 Gen7Context::CheckOOM(unsigned long long, bool&) + 103
3   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver   0x0000000115340edc Gen7Context::ProgramPipeline() + 222
4   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver   0x00000001152bf185 glrIntelBeginPrimitiveBuffer + 325
5   GLEngine                        0x0000000114a4164b gleBeginPrimitiveTCLFunc + 78
6   GLEngine                        0x00000001149e77ea glDrawRangeElements_IMM_Exec + 1051
7   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf18fef CA::OGL::GLContext::draw_elements(CA::OGL::PrimitiveMode, unsigned int, unsigned short const*, CA::OGL::Vertex const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, CA::OGL::ClipPlane const*) + 219
8   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf62889 CA::OGL::Context::array_flush() + 107
9   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf626e9 CA::OGL::Context::ClippedArray::next_rect(CA::Bounds&) + 113
10  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf675ec CA::OGL::emit_one_part_rect(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::RectState const&, float const*, float const*, unsigned int) + 996
11  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf6c991 CA::OGL::fill_rect_tex(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::RectState const&, float const*) + 183
12  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce677e0 CA::OGL::ContentsGeometry::fill_and_unbind(CA::OGL::Context&, CA::OGL::Image*) const + 400
13  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce6a4cd CA::OGL::render_contents_background(CA::OGL::Renderer&, CA::OGL::Layer const*) + 2840
14  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf20f83 CA::OGL::LayerNode::apply(float, CA::OGL::Surface**, float*) + 57
15  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf1f64e CA::OGL::ImagingNode::render(CA::OGL::ImagingNode::RenderClosure*, unsigned int) + 486
16  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce6d8eb CA::OGL::render_layers(CA::OGL::Renderer&, CA::OGL::Layer*) + 206
17  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf21027 CA::OGL::LayerNode::apply(float, CA::OGL::Surface**, float*) + 221
18  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf1f64e CA::OGL::ImagingNode::render(CA::OGL::ImagingNode::RenderClosure*, unsigned int) + 486
19  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce6d8eb CA::OGL::render_layers(CA::OGL::Renderer&, CA::OGL::Layer*) + 206
20  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce6dac9 CA::OGL::render_root_layers(CA::OGL::Renderer&, x_link_struct const*, CA::OGL::Gstate const&) + 343
21  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce46b6b CA::OGL::Renderer::render(CA::Render::Update const*) + 747
22  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcce46ef5 CA::OGL::render(CA::OGL::Renderer&, CA::Render::Update*) + 192
23  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccebbf77 CARenderOGLRenderDisplay + 82
24  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8ab1012 gl_composite_core_animation + 1123
25  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8aa6109 gl_composite_layer_core + 6775
26  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8aa4039 gl_composite_layers + 1317
27  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8aa2fad CGXGLAccelComposite + 653
28  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8b1578a CompositorGL::CompositeLayersToDestination(WSCompositeSourceLayer*, WSCompositeDestination*, unsigned long long) + 124
29  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8a66bc5 WS::DisplaySurface::Composite(CGXRedrawState*, Compositor*, unsigned int, WSCompositeSourceLayer*) + 1181
30  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8afbafe CGXUpdateDisplay + 20486
31  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8af68ad update_display_callback(void*, double) + 216
32  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd8b1d2b5 run_timer_pass + 706
33  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd89c6e9a CGXRunOneServicesPass + 152
34  com.apple.SkyLight              0x00007fffd89c8660 SLXServer + 3853
35  WindowServer                    0x000000010ef96dde 0x10ef96000 + 3550
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffdc6e4255 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc80b38a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc80a7d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc70e8e84 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc70e8301 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffc70e7b54 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.DFRDisplay            0x0000000113fb462d DFRDisplayRunloopThread + 55
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fbaab _pthread_body + 180
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb9f7 _pthread_start + 286
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb1fd thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc80b38a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc80a7d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffcceec1bd CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 254
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffccf9a703 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fbaab _pthread_body + 180
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb9f7 _pthread_start + 286
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb1fd thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc8134e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb5fe _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb1ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffdc8134e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb5fe _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffdc8fb1ed start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fc9b902d000  rbx: 0x00007fff50c65408  rcx: 0x00007fff50c65404  rdx: 0x0000000000000003
  rdi: 0x00007fc9b8c3f710  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x00007fff50c65380  rsp: 0x00007fff50c65380
   r8: 0x00007fff50c652f4   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000001  r11: 0xffff8001c52ad3ac
  r12: 0x0000000000000624  r13: 0x00007fc9b9030d80  r14: 0x00007fc9b902de30  r15: 0x0000f80001f00000
  rip: 0x00007fffd5d8509d  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000000000040

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10ef96000 -        0x10ef96fff  WindowServer (600.00 - 13) <ABFF0AFB-8D9F-392F-9170-889761193646> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Resources/WindowServer
       0x10f0e1000 -        0x10f0e2fff  com.apple.driver.IOAccelerator2D (289.32 - 289.32) <B2D5DFA1-3B26-3BAC-A671-812C0341516A> /System/Library/Extensions/IOAccelerator2D.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOAccelerator2D
       0x10f0f0000 -        0x10f161fff  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsMTLDriver (10.22.29 - 10.2.2) <D17E3B23-1C8F-3DD6-82C6-C1DEB2F12E8F> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsMTLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsMTLDriver
       0x10fa00000 -        0x110132fff  CursorAsset (122.8) <DF959BAA-206B-397B-B605-5190A4BB7203> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/Resources/CursorAsset
       0x113fb1000 -        0x113fb8fff  com.apple.DFRDisplay (1.0 - 1) <BBA4F5BD-1E55-3408-A160-57D2FFEADB83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DFRDisplay.framework/DFRDisplay
       0x114141000 -        0x114144ff3  com.apple.DFRBrightness (1.0 - 1) <20ABE4E4-10EF-3526-AC4F-FED877BD430A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DFRBrightness.framework/DFRBrightness
       0x1148f8000 -        0x1148f8fff  com.apple.WatchdogService (1.0 - 1) <4707FC67-6397-30DD-B233-300ABCD58495> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WatchdogService.framework/WatchdogService
       0x1148fd000 -        0x11490dff7  com.apple.AppleGVACoreFramework (10.1.5 - 10.1.5) <7C95B278-F4F5-33F4-8021-84068FF6B2FB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleGVACore.framework/AppleGVACore
       0x114915000 -        0x114abbfff  GLEngine (13.0.10) <62CCEC13-1EB3-3A65-9224-3DCD2838E0C7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
       0x114af9000 -        0x114c6fffb  libGLProgrammability.dylib (13.0.10) <4C3FD24A-1C43-343E-8EBA-BE1FDCE3F74C> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
       0x114f27000 -        0x1153e3ff7  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver (10.22.29 - 10.2.2) <F60CFC20-FA38-3F61-80C5-F77C9E7BBC21> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver
       0x118947000 -        0x118984267  dyld (421.2) <947FC440-80F9-32F7-A773-6FC418FE1AB7> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fffc3a93000 -     0x7fffc3a93fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <BDDB2053-BB24-34E4-A452-50D1260BF672> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fffc3aac000 -     0x7fffc40ecfe3  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <77F96C96-725E-31E5-8072-D09C6BD988A2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fffc40ed000 -     0x7fffc42b4fef  libBLAS.dylib (1185) <0D55CF73-6DBD-3D15-B500-189479638551> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fffc42b5000 -     0x7fffc42ccfff  libBNNS.dylib (14) <43A9B06E-3C21-3CE6-B0C1-99DA172DEEB0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fffc42cd000 -     0x7fffc46d8fff  libLAPACK.dylib (1185) <E7AE9C48-6E42-3EB7-A257-D48E0CB48D00> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fffc46d9000 -     0x7fffc46effff  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1185) <08F00EFB-B477-3421-906E-3D364E607E6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fffc46f0000 -     0x7fffc46f6fff  libQuadrature.dylib (3) <120F6228-A3D4-3184-89D7-785ADC2AC715> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fffc46f7000 -     0x7fffc470aff7  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1185) <912E3D25-27C0-3245-B64C-3CAD43A5D633> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fffc470b000 -     0x7fffc4858ff7  libvDSP.dylib (600) <87EF1D0A-1F85-31DD-AD8F-AB31E7D8E73B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fffc4859000 -     0x7fffc4910fff  libvMisc.dylib (600) <F6EA539E-0A90-3F8A-9ECA-001E46394E29> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fffc4911000 -     0x7fffc4911fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <B4B785D8-CB43-3E5D-AE81-1F27885AA112> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fffc4bd1000 -     0x7fffc59a3ff3  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 1504.81.100) <0CCB2E18-076E-3D8A-A777-A6E57EF2570A> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fffc59b5000 -     0x7fffc59b5fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <237200C2-28A6-3C19-B34B-53C953F8AE42> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fffc59b6000 -     0x7fffc5a24ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (377 - 422.2) <3680281F-DB99-3CA2-9C76-CABFC8DBC980> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fffc5abe000 -     0x7fffc5bedfff  libFontParser.dylib (194.6) <F3DF2CF7-B25D-30BB-9EE6-1EA9F3B8A066> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fffc5bee000 -     0x7fffc5c38fff  libFontRegistry.dylib (196.3) <855AF921-EAE0-3D07-B161-5EF09806B643> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fffc5d34000 -     0x7fffc5ddeff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.12.0 - 502.1) <5F244DE3-A6E8-335F-AE3B-25F0E407DD62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fffc5ddf000 -     0x7fffc5e2fff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 591) <34C950CC-1084-354A-BCE6-9396EDB29DF8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fffc5e30000 -     0x7fffc5e3fff3  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <47D1A017-91A4-37F3-93E0-3923CD6ED2DE> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fffc5e40000 -     0x7fffc5e8dfff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (12 - 491) <B7CC15C1-AF50-37F3-8AF6-65F8CDC323F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fffc5e8e000 -     0x7fffc5ec9fff  com.apple.QD (3.12 - 310) <8F718290-DD82-36CE-9AF0-EFB6D31A49F4> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
    0x7fffc5eca000 -     0x7fffc5ed5ff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (6.3.3 - 6.3.3) <629831B1-B13C-30F5-AE16-6BB9037E3753> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fffc5ed6000 -     0x7fffc60e6fff  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <A1B98513-C19E-376F-8DAF-71BB2F263C5F> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fffc60e7000 -     0x7fffc60e7fff  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.14 - 1.14) <55C6A958-D52B-3D81-B230-EB949212B5D9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fffc6250000 -     0x7fffc6623ff7  com.apple.CFNetwork (807.2.14 - 807.2.14) <9702C8B9-2984-3DD9-9C59-A83499C2DBC4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fffc6642000 -     0x7fffc694aff7  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 856.13) <98D5D2A7-55A6-31A7-9056-CC48EBB16654> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fffc6955000 -     0x7fffc69ecff3  com.apple.ink.framework (10.9 - 219) <B44BA36D-7549-3EB2-8CF6-E171885194FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
    0x7fffc6a0d000 -     0x7fffc6a13ff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework (6.0.1 - 6.0.1) <A20B0F7B-C32A-3FF1-BB75-BAC0EE4EF889> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fffc6af2000 -     0x7fffc6af2fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <CF1AD0E9-2257-35FE-B719-760B58E405C9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fffc6c32000 -     0x7fffc6cc2ff7  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.3.0 - 4.3.0) <A38A11A5-130B-39CE-BEBA-F5427F6801DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fffc6cc3000 -     0x7fffc6cd6fff  com.apple.CoreBluetooth (1.0 - 1) <76AFC4B4-A9FD-3434-B168-90087E71F5C4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/CoreBluetooth
    0x7fffc6cd7000 -     0x7fffc6fd5fff  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 752.8) <694F9EA9-A785-3F84-8EB1-DAF76E3BDF9B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fffc6fd6000 -     0x7fffc7062fff  com.apple.CoreDisplay (1.0 - 1) <48B568C0-1E12-34F4-943D-EAB447FBA1BE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
    0x7fffc7063000 -     0x7fffc74f7ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1348.28) <0F1FAA52-1C06-327E-A170-382B48B1846D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fffc74f8000 -     0x7fffc7b9bff7  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1070.13.2) <ACB5545C-FE91-36C9-8F02-87DF6904A911> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fffc7b9c000 -     0x7fffc7ddefff  com.apple.CoreImage (12.2.0 - 451.3.1) <CDAD60F3-74F6-3EA5-A8B5-B42476E350FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
    0x7fffc7f43000 -     0x7fffc7f43fff  com.apple.CoreServices (775.9.7 - 775.9.7) <A5C444F3-408B-3062-AF4B-BF8CD919F221> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fffc7f44000 -     0x7fffc7f95fff  com.apple.AE (712.2 - 712.2) <342A13C0-4A6A-3947-B66B-0F624A4A7B52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fffc7f96000 -     0x7fffc8271ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1159.5 - 1159.5) <11CC2194-0C9C-397A-B7F9-CDAB9B68D87D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fffc8272000 -     0x7fffc82a5fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 274) <864F3808-FFDD-3C4B-A5B7-F1A6C4668A86> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fffc82a6000 -     0x7fffc82aeffb  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1230 - 1230) <13A2FC17-8F8C-35BF-9584-59FDFB738E2B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fffc82af000 -     0x7fffc841bff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (775.9.7 - 775.9.7) <E350E4F6-822A-3F04-B59B-468A39AF5C64> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fffc841c000 -     0x7fffc84ccfff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 1075.28) <DBB524CD-6938-3623-99C2-4B1EC1E1BE58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fffc84cd000 -     0x7fffc852cfff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (775.9.7 - 775.9.7) <E9625B0B-9AE7-3024-9FEF-FEE0A1876D9D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fffc852d000 -     0x7fffc859dfff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <F1B3EF8D-E820-317C-AC7F-8F056C246874> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fffc859e000 -     0x7fffc85e4ff7  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (38 - 38) <E1400999-1F08-35A1-9D07-27D80A2AF89A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fffc8671000 -     0x7fffc87bdff7  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 544.5) <E90EA1D8-3491-3014-9043-9928C4E4349C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fffc87be000 -     0x7fffc87f3fff  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 234.0) <48C31E93-87C2-31F4-97E7-9E54C1EA8E7D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fffc87f4000 -     0x7fffc8865ffb  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (11.0 - 1200.25.1) <BEBE9C03-3B9A-3948-99E3-CC8148FA2AB5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fffc8964000 -     0x7fffc8969fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <16EA6D93-A2EC-31DB-BF52-C4764E7B1630> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fffc8af8000 -     0x7fffc8e9fff3  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1349.25) <D820A498-2E62-367D-BC72-5845B14C06E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fffc8ecb000 -     0x7fffc8efcfff  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <95FAD1F9-1610-3428-B9B4-D32F67C26574> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fffc8fbc000 -     0x7fffc905fffb  com.apple.Bluetooth (5.0.3 - 5.0.3f1) <CCB4E097-1ED0-3439-8450-2B6EFFBC4608> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/A/IOBluetooth
    0x7fffc9060000 -     0x7fffc90f5ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1324.30.13) <163BE7FA-B29A-348F-8B5F-E301F2E8C964> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fffc90f6000 -     0x7fffc90fcffb  com.apple.IOSurface (153.3 - 153.3) <3DD3BF22-0800-31F2-B179-87F87D6F0548> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fffc914e000 -     0x7fffc92aaff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.3.0 - 1582) <A9A63D25-DA38-33C0-98C6-F015952568B2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fffc92ab000 -     0x7fffc92affff  libGIF.dylib (1582) <B0435621-A64F-3E0E-AC03-35ED505A61B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
```

Comment: I've had this a few times while viewing youTube videos using Chrome. Pretty shocking to crash so hard. Required a restart since other apps were unstable after logging in (e.g. Firefox reported that it was already running when it wasn't). No idea as to cause.